# why is my text input border not showing up when set?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to apply an error class of a red border color to my text input field like so:

jquery

```
//save
...
$("input.required").each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){                               
        $(this).addClass("form_error");
        formValid = false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass("form_error");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="city_id">City</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="span2 required" type="text" value="" name="test" id='testId'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
textarea,
input[type="text"]{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.form_error {
  border-color: #ee5f5b;
  border: 1px solid #ee5f5b;
}
```

This is working for my select elements but not text inputs.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: do you have any `border` or `border-color` css rules defined after the `.form-error` rule? Check how the css rules are applied in firebug to see it the red border rule is not overriden. If possible maybe post an url to the page

Comment: Try changing the class from "span2 required" to just "required".

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me, is it sure you don't have errors somewhere else? I have a pretty much similar code that works. Also, copied yours, it also works: http://jsfiddle.net/8kM5c/

Comment: @AlexW: nah, multiclasses are one of the few good things about CSS actually, and this code does work.

Comment: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and it looks like they define the border color prior to my style, but should my addClass call over-right that?

Comment: @Aadaam While they are supported in the major browsers, really old browsers don't support them. So you should make sure that the first class you list is the one with the most specific information for that element.

Comment: `addClass` just adds a class to the element. The override is done by the css rules (if that is the case here). Check in firebug or chrome dev tools how the styles are applied to your element and most notably if the `form_error` class is actually applied (altough from the code I see no reason why it shouldn't be)

Comment: @AlexW: it's supported from IE7 and up, IE6 has largely diminished from the web (thank God, if you allow me this slightly religios remark)

Comment: If it is indeed overriden a last case solution would be to use `border-color: #ee5f5b !important;` but I don't advise it unless no other solution is available

Comment: adding !important solved my issue, that'll have to do for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul Try inspecting a text input, in whatever browser your using to see what CSS is being applied: http://cms.about.com/od/cms-basics/a/Get-The-Inspect-Element-Tool-For-Your-Browser.htm

Comment: if `!important` works then the rule was definatly overriden. If you don't have any other classes applied in other places on the same elements that have `form_error` then you should be ok. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me if I remove the

```
textarea,
input[type="text"]{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

part. I'm guessing that your class is getting applied, but the element styling is getting applied last and ends up winning.

If removing the section above isn't an option, you can also try changing .form_error to be

```
.form_error {
  border-color: #ee5f5b;
  border: 1px solid #ee5f5b !important;
}
```

which will make sure that .form_error's styling wins over the element styling. It's a little kludgy, but it will work (at least in Chrome, which is where I'm testing this).

Comment: This is not a matter of rule _order_, but of _Specificity_ – `.form_error` has a Specificity of `0-0-1-0`, whereas `input[type="text"]` has one of `0-0-1-1`.

Comment: +1 to CBroe - somehow I'd never heard the term 'specificity' applied to CSS. So I've learned something new today, and suddenly a lot of things make more sense. Thanks!

This seems like a pretty good explanation of the topic: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

you might need to specify a border style too:

```
border: 1px solid #ee5f5b;
```